# Jquery Datatable sum of columns shows invalid result

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable footer callback to find sum of two columns. For the first two columns it gives correct sum value at the footer. But for the 3rd column it gives a result like this : `1.0771827874123119e-11` since the 3rd column contains negative values. Is it because of negative values. How can I solve this?

I am using the following javascript:

```
$('.dataTablesSum1').DataTable({
            "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(), data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(2)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                total1 = api
                   .column(3)
                   .data()
                   .reduce(function (a, b) {
                       return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                   }, 0);

                total3 = api
                   .column(4)
                   .data()
                   .reduce(function (a, b) {
                       return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                   }, 0);




                // Update footer

                $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
                    total
                );
                $(api.column(3).footer()).html(
                    total1
                );
                $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
                    total3
                );
            }
        });
```

Comment: To parse your value into **Int** you can simply use **parseInt**

Comment: But column contains decimal values like 12.35 and even negative values -2.56. So do i need to make any changes on above script?

Comment: Yes, You need to change above script and use parseFloat

Comment: Still shows same error

Comment: Perhaps a small JSFiddle to illustrate your issue might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with JS - it's not good at float arithmetic, try this in a console:

`-5000.02 + 7000.00`

it returns "1999.9799999999996".

To work around this issue, restrict the number of decimal places with `toFixed()`, see [a live example here](http://live.datatables.net/lobijosi/1/edit).

Comment: Yes . I fixed...:)